# What are the names corresponding to grad, rot (curl) and div in the 2-dimensional vector analyis?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, vector-analysis

$\mathrm{Grad}$, $\mathrm{rot}$ ($\mathrm{curl}$) and $\mathrm{div}$ are the notions of the 3-dimensional vector analysis. They replace the notion of the exterior derivative of $k$-forms in the case of $k=0,1$ and $2$, respectivelly.

But, what is the situation in the 2-dimensional vector analysis?

On a 2-dimensional differentiable manifold, the exterior derivative of a $0$-form is also an $1$-form, so it can be identified with a vector field, just as in the 3-dimensional vector analysis. So, $\mathrm{Grad}$ is a good name for it in this case too. But in 2-dimensions, the exterior derivative of a $1$-form is a $2$-form, and the latter can be identified with a $0$-form, so this operation assigns a scalar field to a vector field, so it corresponds to the 3-dimensional $\mathrm{div}$. But the name of the operation that corresponds to the exterior derivative of a  $1$-form in the 3-dimensional vector analysis is  $\mathrm{rot}$ ($\mathrm{curl}$). Then what is the name of the integrand on the right side of [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem)? $\mathrm{rot}$ ($\mathrm{curl}$), or  $\mathrm{div}$, or something else?

Comment: It can be either one. If you are doing a work line integral over the boundary, it's curl; if you are doing a flux line integral over the boundary, it's div. (As in 3D, it's the Hodge star operator that turns the work $1$-form into the flux $1$-form — instead of the flux $2$-form.)

Comment: Curl does not generalize in this way to 4 or more dimensions (or down to 2 or fewer dimensions) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)#Generalizations

Comment: @Miguel: Curl is fine in 2D because 2D sits naturally inside 3D. But in dimensions $\ge 4$, we have to work with differential forms and the exterior derivative.